# how can i view my visual basic project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I just found an old usb drive with my senior project from school on it. It's a asp.net visual basic project, but I don't know know/remember(?) how to open it.

It has a bunch of `.aspx` and `.aspx.vb` and `.master` and `.master.vb` files.

I just want to be able to open this and check out the project I built a long time ago. Anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here are the contents of my Login.aspx.vb file

```
Partial Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnEmployer_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEmployer.Click
        Response.Redirect("~/clientLogin.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnEmployee_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEmployee.Click
        Response.Redirect("~/employeeLogin.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Contents of Login.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" Runat="Server">
    <p>
        Select Account Login Type</p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEmployer" runat="server" style="height: 26px" 
            Text="Employer" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEmployee" runat="server" Text="Employee" />
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Here are the contents of my Home.aspx.vb file:

```
Partial Class Home
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

Contents of Home.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/loggedinMasterClient.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Home.aspx.vb" Inherits="Home" title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphData" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat ="Server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Ok, so because you have CodeFile="Home.aspx.vb" (instead of "CodeBehind"), I'm pretty sure it means you had an original "Web Project".  So if you open as a "Web Project", and it won't run, then you're either missing files (that you wrote) OR you could be missing "Third Party References" that were on your original development computer.  You may be chasing a red-herring, but if you want to post your web.config file.........(and X out any sensitive data), that could provide a few clues.  And PS what happens when you open it as a Web Project, does it fail to load or fail to compile?

Comment: Well I guess I'm not even really able to open as a project. Since I don't have any .sln, .dsw, .vcw, or .vbproj files, I'm unable to even try to open. I suppose I'll just forget about it for now.. It's not important that I accomplish this.. was just hoping for a chance to check out the project again. Thanks for all of your help granadaCoder. I really appreciate it, even if it was for naught.

Comment: The Web PROJECT allows you ~not~ to need a .sln or .vbproj file.  It was kind of the "hobbyist" way to create websites.  As a last effort, you could try creating a NEW WebProject, and then copy over all your files that do not already exist.  There is a button in VS that is "show ALL files", and then you can right click your files and say "include in project".  You could at least bring up your pages in the VS designer this way.  Again, create a NEW webproject, then copy over your files, then include them "one at a time" in the project.

Comment: "one at time" actually means "one file, with this child files" at a time.  Aka, you should add the .aspx and the aspx.vb file (and maybe the designer??) file at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Web Developer Express....... is what I would try first.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Comment: What year were you a Sr?  That would give context to what version you first used.  But with .master pages, I'm thinking later than 2005.

Comment: I'm thinking it was in 2011

Comment: Ok, then yeah, the link I provide will get you going.  Use the "Open Existing Web PROJECT" menu item...or something like that.  "Opening Existing" and "Web Project" are you most likely suspects.

Comment: You can't remember that 2 years ago you were a Sr??  (haha)

Comment: I installed Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010 and was unsuccessful in opening my project. Do you think It'd even make a difference if I tried 2012 version?

Comment: Do you have a .csproj or .vbproj file anywhere?

Comment: eh, two years is a pretty long time.. I was mostly in charge of the database portion of the project, although since my project group was 50% worthless I did work on some of the vb, but I haven't used any vb since :-/. No other files are present, except my web.config and some DB files

Comment: So the absence of a vbproj file definitely suggests a "Web Project", (as opposed to a Web Application).  The little poopty is that a vbproj file would provide hints need to say "This project was first developed in Visual Studio Version __________".  But regardless.  Can you post one of your myfile.aspx.vb files (the contents), that ~might provide a clue.

Comment: add the contents of a couple of my .aspx.vb files to original post

Comment: Ok, can you add the .aspx contents (of your example).  (Sorry I should have asked for both at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

Look for a .sln or .vbproj file. If you find one, download and install a copy of [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products). The current version of Visual Studio should be able to open your old project. Just be warned: it will probably have to convert it to the current format first.

If you can't find a .sln or .vbproj file, this is likely the deployed version of the project. In that case, you want to make sure you're on a version of Windows that supports IIS (Home Premium versions of Windows tend to *not* support this). IIS is not installed in any modern version of Windows by default — you have to add it manually — so you'll also need to make sure it's installed and running by looking in the Windows Programs and Features area. Once this is done, you'll likely have a folder on your hard drive like this:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Copy the entire contents of your thumb drive to that folder, and then point your web browser here:

```
http://localhost/
```

If all goes well, you'll see your project.

It's also possible that your project relies on a database connection of some kind. For a school project where you learned VB.Net WebForms, this database likely involved Sql Server. Your Visual Studio Express install should have allowed you to install Sql Server Express Edition as well, but you may still need to set up a user account or load the database into the server... unfortunately, that's outside the scope of what I can walk you through without a lot more info.

Comment: This didn't work. All I end up getting is a directory listing of my files. Also, I tried installing Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010 and it was unable to open my project. I don't understand how but I must be missing some file(s)..

Comment: Hey, that's good! It means your site probably at least compiled. Look for a file named index.apsx or default.aspx and trying browsing directly to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Visual Studio Express` to open the files.

Download [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express)

Also if you want to build the project successfully you might want to check the Database involved. Download the express edition of the [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1695)

Make sure the connection strings are in place in the `web.config` file.